# Ruby failed to rackup - uninitialized constant Dry::Validation::Contract

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rackup

My laptop is MacOS m1 chip, when I was using rackup to run the app, it showed `uninitialized constant Dry::Validation::Contract (NameError) Did you mean?  Dry::Container`, I have no idea about it and didn't find an answer on the Internet.

Here's my Gemfile.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.7.3'

# PRESENTATION LAYER
gem 'slim'

# APPLICATION LAYER
# Web application related
gem 'econfig'
gem 'puma'
gem 'roda'

# Controllers and services
gem 'dry-monads'
gem 'dry-transaction'
gem 'dry-validation'

...
```

Also put the Gemfile.lock here

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    ...
    dry-validation (0.12.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      dry-configurable (~> 0.1, >= 0.1.3)
      dry-core (~> 0.2, >= 0.2.1)
      dry-equalizer (~> 0.2)
      dry-logic (~> 0.4, >= 0.4.0)
      dry-types (~> 0.13.1)
    ...

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  ...
  dry-monads
  dry-transaction
  dry-validation
  ...

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.7.3p183

BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.21
```

Hope someone can help, thanks!

Comment: Can you post the full (or at least) a longer stack trace and preferably the relevant part of the file it is point to?

Comment: @engineersmnky Here's the stack trace
https://gist.github.com/tienyulin/2a8cebd69b31d7aba13465cacc345328

Comment: @engineersmnky Here's the file using dry validation https://gist.github.com/tienyulin/1f6813d24ce316c08de1a3b8708748c7

Comment: You will need to make sure `Dry::Validation::Contract` is available to that file. Either require it up front or require it specifically in the files it is needed (likely a better option) I.e. add `require 'dry/validation'` to the file

Comment: Yeah, I've already added `require dry-validation` in another file that I use require_relative to import it. I also tried to add this require into this file, still not work.

Comment: Well `dry-validation` requires contract https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-validation/blob/master/lib/dry/validation.rb so it is unclear how to solve your issue if what your saying is 100% accurate.